# Touch Screen Laptops Emulator for Testing

Tags: testing, touch, screen, emulation

Can someone advise testing tool which emulates touch screen laptops fully? Something like [BrowserStack](https://www.browserstack.com) or [CrossBrowserTesting](https://crossbrowsertesting.com/). I know about chrome [toggle device toolbar](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/emulate-mobile-viewports) but it's not covering all areas.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think both CBT and BrowserStack will suit you well. They both offer unlimited automation testing plans for decent prices and have good support for a lot of the popular testing frameworks. They both have really good support for a ton of OS/Browser configurations that scale from desktop to mobile/tablets. It boils down to which tool will fit your specific needs the best. Don't think you can go wrong with either.